# PyQT How to check if Signal is already blocked

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, signals

What would be a way to check if a widget has been already disconnected using

```
myCoolWidget.blockSignals(True)
```

(**.blockSignals(True)** is used to break a relationship between a widget itself and a function(-s) it was connected).

I would like to be able to check/see/query if a particular widget is in its 'unblocked' or 'blocked' state with the function. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `blockSignals()` function stops the object _emitting_ signals - it doesn't disconnect anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Widget.blockSignals() returns a bool value of it's current state upon call. There's also bool Widget.signalsBlocked() function which does exactly what you need.